# Formatting text

Tags: formatting

I have a two part question:

1. Is it possible using Latex to lay out text in the following format:

   ```
   Stage Directions                    Text


   A Character Name                    Some Dialogue


   Another Character name              Some further dialogue
   ```

   I have tried using `Character \> \> Dialogue \\` but, this doesn't seem to work.
2. Could someone advise me on the best document class to use for this.

Many thanks.
Mike

Comment: ``Formatting text'' - isn't that why we're all here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}


\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=5em,labelwidth=5em,labelsep=0pt,
label={\smash{\small\itshape\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Stage\\ Directions\end{tabular}}},
align=left,font=\bfseries]

\item\lipsum[3]  
\item[Tom] \lipsum[1]  
\item[Jerry] \lipsum[2]  

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David - is it possible to enlarge the gap between 'Tom' and 'lipsum' etc... I would like to achieve a gap of about 1 inch if possible. Mike

Comment: Sorry - I'm slow tonight. I have solved it thank you. I simply increased labelsep=0pt to labelsep=50pt, and that opens the space :-).

Answer (score 7):

Note that `play.cls` is designed to typeset specifically this kind of material and can be customised in various ways.

Here's a simple, default example:

```
\documentclass{play}
\title{A Play}
\author{Will}
\newcommand*\character[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{thesetting}
  Setting for play.
  \character{Character} is $\phi$ing.
  \character{Other character} is $\psi$ing.
  \character{Another character} is $\alpha$ing.
\end{thesetting}

\begin{play}

\speaker{Character} Witty remark.
\speaker{Other character} Riposte.
  \shortdirection{\character{Character} $\mu$s $x$ to \character{Other character}.}
  Follow-up

\longdirection{\character{Character} and \character{Other character} exit, $\delta$ing, stage right.}

\speaker{Another character} speaks to him/her self.

\end{play}
\end{document}
```

[image: play]